# LCP EchoReq постоянный запрос в логах микротика, как отключить?

Tags: mikrotik

Подскажите пж как отключить постоянную отправку ppoe-out 1 sent LCP EchoReq id=0x23 запросов в  логах.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

system-> logging - отключи лишние топики